# How to catch and save compile time and run time errors of my solution project in Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime, compile-time

I am currently trying to figure out a way on how I can possibly save the compile time and runtime errors (in database tables) that the project/solution/website in my visual studio solution explorer could possibly throw.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**Update:** For now I would want to log the errors only for C# language.

I am desperately looking for a way or solution to implement this...any help will be deeply appreciated...

NiK.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to save compile errors to a dbase?  Fix them instead.

Comment: @Hans...I think I am good enough to fix the errors...I have posted this question in search of an answer not to hear ppl asking why and per my requirement I need to log these errors...please respond to questions only if you think you know something about it...sorry if was a bit rude... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to look into developing an extension to visual studio, similar to Jetbrain's Resharper.  Visual Studio exposes a rich api for interacting with the IDE itself.  If you are using command line builds outside of visual studio, you may need to pipe the output to a file and parse it.

Here's a few links to get you started on developing an extension/add-in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968855

And here's a link for a video for integrating with the error list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc563922

Runtime errors may be easier since there is an appdomain exception event that you can handle.  You can wire up a handler to this event and log the exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

For handled exceptions, there are a couple of techniques.  Microsoft has an exception handling block that can be used, or you could create a custom exception type that you use throughout the application.

Answer (score 5):

Compile time errors are saved in a html buildlog, check your output window for the link. Shouldn't be too hard to put in a database. A piece of software that does use this information is CruiseControl.Net, so you could probably learn from looking at their code.

For runtime errors, it's impossible to answer. First of all, it's unclear what you are asking. By "runtime errors", do you mean exception eg divide by zero? Second, this is also very different between different languages supported in VS, eg .NET languages and straight C++.

Update: Since you're on the .NET platform, I suggest you either wrap your main function with a try/catch block that catches all thrown errors, and just log all the information you can get from that error to your database (eg stack trace, Exception kind, perhaps a minidump). This, of course, will not work with errors that are caught or swallowed. In case you would also want  to log those (for whatever reason), you would have to do some more clever source transformations, for example by using reflection. An example would be to add logging to the constructor of the base class Exception.

Comment: @El...I think even though you deal with different programming languages in VS a runtime error is something that gets thrown while your application/process/project is running after the build is succeeded. Say for example you have a statement int i = x/y and y is a dynamically passed value from an outside component. Now for some reason if the outside component sends a null for 'y' then the application would throw an error what is called a runtime error and I believe the concept/theory will be same for other languages too.

Comment: The concept/theory sure, the implementation is a whole other story though, in the case of C++. Consider the fact you can turn off exceptions entirely in Visual Studio. But this is academic since you're on the .NET platform.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want this for a website.  You can create a Global class (Global.asax.vb) and then handle the error in the Application_Error event.  This is where you deal with any unhandled exceptions (vb example is what I have):

```
    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when an error occurs
    Dim appException As System.Exception = Server.GetLastError()
    Dim tempException As System.Exception = Nothing

    If appException Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    tempException = appException.InnerException
```

tempException will hold the unhandled exception and you can store it in a database, or email it to someone.  Your choice.

You can do something very similar in winform apps by handling the _unhandledException event in the Application events.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Project files are MSBuild files which can contain custom compilation steps. Maybe it's possible to replace the compilation step with a custom step which calls the CSharp compiler and logs the error.

If you give us a bit more information on what you want to use it for, maybe we can provide alternative solutions. For example do you need to log the errors from inside visual studio or is it enough to have an external tool log these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Only the C++ compiler does a buildlog. C# does not. You will have to either go the plugin/extension route (in which case, use Dave Ferguson's suggestions to get started) or you can use the command line to compile (csc.exe) and pipe the output to a file (csc.exe /options >> log.txt), and parse it.

Comment: Oh and as far as run time goes, look into something like ELMAH or just hook into the application error event as has been suggested.